# How can I override the attribute assignment in an active record object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know you can do this with virtual attributes, but what if the column actually exists?

For example, my model has a `raw_topic` column. When `raw_topic` is set, I want `artist` and `song_title` to be set based off of `raw_topic`'s contents. Ideally, I'd like to override the `raw_topic=` method, but rails doesn't seem to like that.

What's the proper way of doing this? Is a callback the only way?

Comment: I've done similar things in the past, what do mean by "rails doesn't seem to like that", did you get an error when you tried it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def raw_topic=(value)
  # do something with raw topic
  self[:raw_topic] = value
end
```

That way you can ensure you still have the raw topic if you need to act on it.