# Can't get a non-mass-assignment value to set or save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

frustrating simple problem here. I'm using Rails 3.1 and have the following class:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :active
  attr_accessible :roleTagline, :projectTagline, :projectStartDate, :projectDuration, :postedStartDate,
    :postedEndDate, :skillsRequired, :skillsPro, :experiencedRequired, :description, :active
  scope :is_active, :conditions => {:active => 1}

  validates :roleTagline,  :presence => true,
                :length => { :minimum => 5 }
  validates :projectTagline, :presence => true,
                :length => { :minimum => 5 }
  belongs_to :job_provider

#   def active=(act)
#       @active = act
#   end
end
```

In my controller, I'm trying to create a Job using mass-assignment (one of the ActiveRecord build helpers), then afterwards set the "active" attribute to 1 and then save the Job. Here's the controller code:

```
def create
  @job_provider = current_user.job_provider
  @job = @job_provider.jobs.build(params[:job])
  @job.active= 1 # debug logging @job.active here gives an empty string
  if @job.save # etc.
```

I've tried all combinations of removing attr_accessor and writing my own setter instead, but whatever I do I can't seem to find the correct combination to get the attribute to stay on the model. It's not active record I don't think because even before the @job.save the attribute is gone (from using debug logging). I've googled around but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help please?

Edit: schema.rb from rake:

```
create_table "jobs", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "roleTagline"
t.string   "projectTagline"
t.date     "projectStartDate"
t.integer  "projectDuration"
t.date     "postedStartDate"
t.date     "postedEndDate"
t.string   "skillsRequired"
t.string   "skillsPro"
t.string   "experiencedRequired"
t.string   "description"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "active"
t.integer  "job_provider_id"
end
```

Another edit:

Ok after even more Googling I finally found the answer to this here:

[How can I override the attribute assignment in an active record object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528301/how-can-i-override-the-attribute-assignment-in-an-active-record-object)

If you're modifying an ActiveRecord attribute and not a class instance, you need to do:

self[:fieldname] = value

Comment: What does the "@job.save attribute is gone" mean? Also, can you post your schema for the jobs table since its the only thing left that we'd need to replicate your example?

Comment: I tried doing a debug.log using both the to_yaml function and also accessing the object with @job.active and both results and the SQL for the insert show the attribute is not set.

Comment: Trying to get a database scheme now. The 'active' column is an integer.

Comment: Here's a schema.rb from Rake:create_table "jobs", :force => true do |t|

    t.string   "roleTagline"

    t.string   "projectTagline"

    t.date     "projectStartDate"

    t.integer  "projectDuration"

    t.date     "postedStartDate"

    t.date     "postedEndDate"

    t.string   "skillsRequired"

    t.string   "skillsPro"

    t.string   "experiencedRequired"

    t.string   "description"

    t.datetime "created_at"

    t.datetime "updated_at"

    t.integer  "active"

    t.integer  "job_provider_id"

  end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `attr_accessor :active` from the model. It is causing the value to be saved in an instance variable rather than to the database via the `attributes` hash. You don't have to write an accessor, because ActiveRecord does that automatically for you, based on the `active` column.

It's showing up blank in the debug log because it is initialized to nil. If you remove the attr_accessor line and change the `active` column in the database to `NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`, it will be initialized to 0. i.e. `:null => false, :default => 0` in an ActiveRecord migration or schema.rb.

Comment: This is the answer, [here](https://gist.github.com/1908403) is a gist showing that if you just remove the `attr_accessor :active`, then it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't add the job_provider_id to the `att_accessible`. Try the following

```
attr_accessible :roleTagline, :projectTagline, :projectStartDate, :projectDuration, :postedStartDate, :postedEndDate, :skillsRequired, :skillsPro, :experiencedRequired, :description, :active, :job_provider_id
```